# print a Class::Method() when a method is called

Tags: c++

Is there some easy way so that I when a method is called to get class and the method name printed on the screen.. something like this :

```
> class1:method()
> class1:method4()
> class3:method2()
....
```

in a sense insert a "cout" in the beginning of every method w/o actually doing the typing ?

Comment: I'm not sure if `__func__` does the class part. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` probably would, but it's not standard.

Comment: I guess you can write a macro, but why do you want this?

Comment: Probably for debugging perposes? If that is the case, why don't you just use GDB?

Comment: for debugging purposes..